# Multiple Inheritance in Ruby, Java etc

Tags: java, ruby, multiple-inheritance

It may sound silly, but if every class implicitly extends Object class and it is allowed to extend one more class, how is it not multiple inheritance? From user's point of view it may be argued that they don't support multiple inheritance, because user is not allowed to extend more than one class. However, the languages seem to have internal support for multiple inheritance, which is just not exposed to user probably to keep it simple. Am I making sense?

Note: I'm not arguing for or against support of multiple inheritance. Just trying to clarify some thoughts.

Comment: A class doesn't extend "one more class" in addition to Object.  If you don't specify a parent, the default parent is Object.

Comment: Your comment is right on target and I feel really stupid now. But this won't be the first time or last. So every class is NOT implicitly extending the Object, instead it is extending only if there is no parent specified. But every class has access to Object's properties because one way or another it's hierarchy includes Object as the root. So these languages don't have internal or external support of multiple inheritance. Makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Typical OO systems support a *chain* (with arbitrary length) of derived classes. From the point of view of any one subclass, the parents form a chain back to Object. Looking at all of the classes at once, we see that the class hierarchy is really a tree, with a very wide fanout immediately below Object.

What is *not* typical is allowing two branches on the tree to merge again at a class which has *direct* multiple superclasses, and that specifically is what "multiple inheritance" means.

You are correct that it's potentially "multiple" in the english sense either way, but not "multiple" in the OO sense of ultimately being able to pass a single object to multiple interfaces that each require an object of otherwise-unrelated parent classes.

A way to work around this restriction is also typical, which is why you have interfaces in Java and included ("mixin") modules in Ruby.

Comment: Now thats how I need to start thinking :)

Comment: +1, well said. One minor point: "it's really a tree" is a strange diversion from a class model to a class hierarchy, with an antecedent that is missing and differently than implied by the previous sentence.

Comment: +1. We can achieve the goals of multiple inheritance through composition, which is what Java and Ruby are doing. My question was more about if the languages are supporting multiple inheritance, but not exposing to users. David Nehme's comment helped me figure out the flaw in my thought process.

Comment: @Andy - good points, I've updated it to more gracefully transition between topics.

Answer (score 2):

Situation which you described is just pure inheritance, it has nothing in common with multiple inheritance. For example in Java we have `Integer` which inherits from `Number`, and `Number` inherits from `Object`.

Standard example of language with multiple inheritance is C++

```
class A { };
class B { };
class C { };
class X : public A, private B, public C { };
```

Whereas in Java we have

```
class A { }
class B extends A { }
class C extends B { }
class X extends C { }
```

In terms of multiple inheritance Ruby is similar to Java (classes in ruby can have only one ancestor). However Ruby provides different mechanisms that "acts as" multiple inheritance i.e. modules

```
# class XX inherits from CC
class AA 
end
class BB < AA
end
class CC < BB
end
class XX < CC
end

# class X mixin A,B,C modules
module A end
module B end
module C end
class X 
    include A
    include B
    include C
end
```

In Ruby (similarly to Java) class `AA` has default ancestor (inheritance chain depends on Ruby version)

```
X.ancestors
[X, C, B, A, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
XX.ancestors
[XX, CC, BB, AA, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Comment: I like your answer with clear examples and +1 for that. However, I'm not sure if you are right about "Situation which you described is just pure inheritance, it has nothing in common with multiple inheritance." In Java and Ruby, each layer of ancestor can only be one class, which is regular inheritance. I always thought and still think multiple inheritance means the ability to inherit from more than one class at the same time. One of us may be confused about the terminology here, I'll let others weigh in on that. I did find the answer to my original question in comment by David Nehme.

Comment: @Srini K, using mixins is, to some extent, like "using multiple classes at the same time". In ruby, unlike Java, the most basic building block is actually Module, not Class (class inherits Module). When you use mixins, while the effect may "feel like" multiple inheritance, ruby is really just inserting each module into the inheritance chain in the order in which the modules are included.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that "true" multiple inheritance allows you to inherate from difference classes in different class trees.  The problem with that becomes if both classes your child class inherites from have similar properties or methods then you have to deal with that conflict in the child.

In languages like Java, where multiple inheritance is not allowed, identical members are simply overridden by the member in the child class.

In conclusion, even though you can have many classes in your type hierarchy you will only have **one** version of each member, as each child will override parent members with its own.

Answer (score 0):

Everything reference type in Java is a `java.lang.Object`, as you've noted.

Developers who define custom types can be extended using one implementation.  You can choose to implement multiple interfaces, but these don't come with any implementation.  The developer has to add their own.

So you may be strictly correct when you say that custom types in Java receive implementation from both `java.lang.Object` and extended super classes, but it's considered single inheritance of implementation because the developer can only extend one implementation class.

You are arguing semantics.  You *can't* extend multiple implementations in Java.

But you *can* implement multiple interfaces.